# Best Way To Store Images In SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, image, entity-framework

Which is the right way to store images in SQL Server? Is there any way to store them with ADO.NET Entity Framework? I need some good resources of how to do it in the best and modern way.

Comment: Use the [`FILESTREAM`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993(v=sql.105).aspx) column type.

Comment: [To BLOB or Not To BLOB](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64525)

Answer (score 5):

The right way if you ever decide to store images in SQL Server is to use the [FILESTREAM](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) type.

> Is there any way to store them with ADO.NET Entity Framework?

The thing is that FILESTREAM is a SQL Server specific column whereas EF is designed to be database agnostic. So you could have a property of type `byte[]` on your model but EF will not take advantage of streaming. It will load it as standard `varbinary(max)`.

You could also use the native [`SqlFileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlfilestream.aspx) class to work directly with the FILESTREAM column type in ADO.NET. Here's a [`blog post`](http://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2011/08/22/using-sqlfilestream-in-c-to-access-sql-server-filestream-data/) which shows an example.

You might also decide to store files on the file system and save only the file path in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can store images in varbinary format. In the sql database table create two columns of types `varbinary(MAX)` and `varchar(MAX)` (You can use any size) and check "allow nulls".

To Your entity model add two properties:

```
public byte[] ImageData { get; set; } //Your image stored in binary data in the database
public string ImageMimeType { get; set; ) //just a string representation of Your image type,
                                          //this property is optional )
```

To `ImageMimeType` You can apply `HiddenInputAttribute(DisplayValue=false)`. You don't need to apply it to `ImageData` cause the framework doesn't visualize editor for byte arrays.

To save image in the database: (As You can see here the model object is called "product")

```
if (image != null) {
product.ImageMimeType = image.ContentType; 
product.ImageData = new byte[image.ContentLength];
image.InputStream.Read(product.ImageData, 0, image.ContentLength);
}
```

Hope this helps.

p.s. I store images on the filestream and just keep the "file path" in the database.

Comment: Note the imagetype deprecation   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx